# Запутался в PHP и MySql, во всех этих массивах. Помогите пж

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Достал данные из MySql, а именно (1, 1, 2). Но что-то не могу понять, как из

```
$idto = $db->prepare('SELECT id_to FROM message WHERE id_from = :id');
$idto->execute(['id' => $id]);
```

получить массив, а потом из данных этого массива получить еще данные, то есть:

```
foreach ($idto as &$value) {
    $to = $db->prepare('SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = :id');
    $to->execute(['id' => $value]);
}
```

Вообще не могу сообразить как этот массив сделать.
PS. И кстати, я только неделю изучаю PHP с MySql.

Comment: https://youtu.be/asEoBgSEGtk

Comment: `select U.name from users U join message M on U.id=M.id_to where id_from=:id` сразу даст вам список имен. Никогда не делайте на php того, что может сделать за вас сама база данных. почитайте какие нибудь вводные статьи по SQL. для начала надо освоить `join`

Comment: А что делать когда идет повторение? У меня получается 1 результат 2 раза выводится просто из-за того что 2 сообщения ему пришло.

Comment: Использовать GROUP BY. Mike верно говорит, без знания SQL не выйдет каменный цветок.

Comment: Лан пойду читать про JOIN про SQL, может и выйдет что-нибуть.

Comment: ресурс для изучения mysql  http://sql-ex.ru/  ну и наверное http://www.php-s.ru/MySQL/  ...в первом даже есть практические упражнения с возможностью построить запросы онлайн